# Opencover NUnit Coverage generation fails in Jenkins

Tags: .net, unit-testing, jenkins, nunit, opencover

I'm trying to get Jenkins to generate coverage reports using OpenCover. My project has NUnit unit tests.

In Jenkins I'm executing the following script as a Build Step:

```
C:\test-tools\opencover\OpenCover.Console.exe -register:user "-target:C:\test-tools\nunit\bin\nunit3-console.exe" "-targetargs:C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\my-api\workspace\MyAPI.Tests\bin\Release\MyAPI.Tests.dll" "-output:codecoveragereport.xml"

C:\test-tools\reportgenerator\ReportGenerator.exe "-reports:codecoveragereport.xml" "-targetdir:.\coverage"
C:\test-tools\OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter\OpenCoverToCoberturaConverter.exe -input:codecoveragereport.xml -output:codecoveragecobertura.xml -sources:%WORKSPACE%
```

Jenkins Log:

> [workspace] $ powershell.exe "&
>   'C:\Users\SVC-JE~1.WIN\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson2552981969951052571.ps1'"
>   Executing: C:\test-tools\nunit\bin\nunit3-console.exe NUnit Console
>   Runner 3.4.1  Copyright (C) 2016 Charlie Poole
>
> Runtime Environment    OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601
>   Service Pack 1   CLR Version: 4.0.30319.42000
>
> Test Files
>       C:\Program
>       Files
>       (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\my-api\workspace\MyAPI.Tests\bin\Release\MyAPI.Tests.dll
>
> System.Exception: Unable to acquire remote process agent    at
>   NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.CreateAgentAndRunner()    at
>   NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.LoadPackage()    at
>   NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Load()    at
>   NUnit.Engine.Runners.AggregatingTestRunner.LoadPackage()    at
>   NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Load()    at
>   NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.LoadPackage()    at
>   NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner..ctor(IServiceLocator services,
>   TestPackage package)    at
>   NUnit.Engine.TestEngine.GetRunner(TestPackage package)    at
>   NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleRunner.RunTests(TestPackage package,
>   TestFilter filter)    at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleRunner.Execute()
>   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Program.Main(String[] args) Committing... No
>   results, this could be for a number of reasons. The most common
>   reasons are:
>       1) missing PDBs for the assemblies that match the filter please review the
>       output file and refer to the Usage guide (Usage.rtf) about filters.
>       2) the profiler may not be registered correctly, please refer to the Usage
>       guide and the -register switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with `targetsargs`, changing the way I deal with spaces in the path:

```
-targetargs:"\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\my-api\workspace\MyAPI.Tests\bin\Release\MyAPI.Tests.dll"
```